# Trying to assign 2 values or more to a dictionary key using variables?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

Sorry, i'm a bit new to python and any help is appreciated.

I'm trying to assign 2 values to a dictionary key using a variable that is given a value when prompted. I keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Fader\Desktop\List creator.py", line 41, in <module>
myLists[key].append(edit)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    print (list(myLists.keys()))
    key=input("What List would you like edit?")
    myLists.setdefault(key, [])
    edit=input("What would you like to add?")
    myLists[key].append(edit)
```

Im trying to prompt for a key. Set that key as the default and then prompt for an edit and append the edit to the specified key.

Comment: `setdefault` sets the key only if it doesn't exists, if there's already a key then `myLists.setdefault(key, [])` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of `default` you mean `initial` value.

Please change the third line to this, and check if this is what you meant:

```
myLists[key] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ashwini Chaudhary mentioned, the most likely reason this is occuring is because you already have a key in the dictionary like that.  You could try this to clear the existing values:

```
myLists[key] = myLists[key] if isinstance(myLists.get(key), list) else [])
```

or if for some reason you wanted to keep the word that was already there:

```
myLists[key] = myLists[key] if isinstance(myLists.get(key), list) else 
               [myLists[key]] if isinstance(myLists.get(key), str) else
               []
```

but that there's probably some other data processing methods you should be doing instead :P